# AWS Application Loadbalancer and session stickyness

Tags: aws-application-load-balancer

I have configured AWS load balancer through controller and it's all working i.e., I can reach backend service. I then attempted to set duration based session stickyness. For that I went into the console and set the duration cookie for 1 day as described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/sticky-sessions.html.

Sure enough after that I stared getting AWSALB cookie. However the value of it changes every time I reload the service. The reason for that is the response code is 304 and there's no link in there I can use to get back to the service in the same session.

Is this enough to say the session stickyness is working or should I deploy an app and have a session with it?